# Python list temproray variable or seperate items

Tags: python, list

I've been looking for the answer to this question for a long time, but I couldn't find a solution. I am waiting for your help, thank you in advance.
With python

```
list1 = ["data1","data2","data3","data4","data5"]

output = [    
[list1[0],list1[1]],
[list1[2],list1[3]],
[list1[4]]
        ]
output=[["data1","data2"],["data3","data4"],["data5"]]
```

How can it provide this output?
Can I create a temporary variable in a list and do that.

Comment: This code does exactly what you want.  What is your question?

Comment: You can do something like: `[list1[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(list1), 2)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
list1 = ["data1","data2","data3","data4","data5"]
out = []
i = 0

while True:

    #print("i", i)

    if i == len(list1)-1:
        out.append([list1[-1]])
        break
    elif i > len(list1)-1:
        break
    else:
        out.append([list1[i], list1[i+1]])
    i += 2
print(out)
```

Comment: Not pythonic but a valid solution.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. If you print output (e.g. `print(output)` ) you get

`[['data1', 'data2'], ['data3', 'data4'], ['data5']]`

which is what your are looking for.

'*Output*' will be a list of lists which is allowed in python.